# How can I use a docker image for ATS?

Tags: ats

I have some knowledge of using docker images. I found one for ATS at:

https://hub.docker.com/r/dockerhwxi/ats2/

But I do not know how to use it (as there is current no documentation). Could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow below Steps :

1. Install Docker (**Ref :** https://docs.docker.com/install/ )
2. docker pull dockerhwxi/ats2:v0.3.9
3. docker run -ti -v dockerhwxi/ats2:v0.3.9

Optionally, after docker installation you can clone below repository and run **install.sh** file

https://github.com/steinwaywhw/docker-ats

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Download the image:

`docker pull dockerhwxi/ats2:v0.3.9`

Step 2: Run the image (to produce a container of the name myproject):

`docker run --name myproject -ti -v /path/to/myproject:/MyRoot/myproject dockerhwxi/ats2:v0.3.9`

You can exit the container and restart it later:

`docker start -ai myproject`